# Rails find_by_sql not returning results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

So my query I am running is returning an array with an id and nothing else.  But when I run the same query in psql it returns back the correct records.  Any idea why this could be, or if there may be a better way of executing this query?

rails console

`numbers = RoboDial.find_by_sql "SELECT p.id, p.nam_last, w.warn_closed_date, w.warn_date_issued, pn.phone_number, w.collection_amount FROM people p LEFT OUTER JOIN warrants w ON p.id = w.person_id LEFT OUTER JOIN pn ON p.id = pn.person_id where p.id = 81437"`

Returns this which is not correct

`[#<RoboDial id: 81437>, #<RoboDial id: 81437>]`

Am I doing something wrong here? When I run this same query in a `psql` session it returns back all the correct values.

Correct values would include the below

`p.id, p.nam_last, w.warn_closed_date, w.warn_date_issued, pn.phone_number, w.collection_amount`

Comment: Have you tried inspecting `#<RoboDial id: 81437>, #<RoboDial id: 81437>`?  You're querying on `RoboDial`, so any attributes not in `RoboDial` are not shown, the values should be there which you'd see if you inspected each returned objects.

Comment: Define "not correct"; what do you expect to see?

Comment: it should return back all of the values I selected in the query.

Comment: why are you using the model robodial when you dont select anything from robodials table? What class of records do you expect to get back?